# "Out of Application Memory" Error MacBook Pro (retina) [Mavericks]

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, error, vmware

Looking for some information on this issue.

I have a brand new Macbook pro with nothing on it and am trying to download VMware Fusion 6.0 which is about 530 MB, with no other applications running other than Safari.

I get 1/5 to 1/2 way thru the download and the system gives me this error and asks me to start shutting down applications (only Finder and Safari show in window).  Then it quickly freezes and I have to hard-reboot to recover.

Apple support doesn't know what problem is and is not saying much about if they have ever had someone else report this issue.  Seems to be a lot online about this problem so this is hard to believe.  Does anyone have any information about this issue and if Apple has actually acknowledged the problem yet?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the memory consumption in Activity Monitor?

Comment: What is the Link you are downloading the VMware Fusion 6.0 from ?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to recommend a straight-forward solution, but here are some things I would do to isolate/resolve the issue:

- Open your Activity monitor in Utilities and look at the memory tab/Load.
- Use another browser (Firefox, Chrome) to see whether the problem is related to Safari
- Log in as another user (create new account if necessary) and try from there to see whether it is account-related
- Quit Safari and delete `~/Library/Safari/Downloads.plist`
- Last not least check your download source (link) for the VMware Fusion 6.0